# how can I make ROS STACK?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to build my own stack ,How can I do it ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/70021/how-can-i-make-ros-stack?/) by [eng.mostafa](https://answers.ros.org/users/4980/eng.mostafa/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-07-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A good place to start is going through the [tutorials](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials).

**Update:** To create a new stack, see [this answer](http://answers.ros.org/question/60409/how-to-create-a-stack-in-fuerte/?answer=60541#post-id-60541).

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2013-07-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [eng.mostafa](https://answers.ros.org/users/4980/eng.mostafa/) on 2013-08-04**:
I,have read these tutorials but I cannot find any one talking about this.

**Comment by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on 2013-08-12**:
Ah okay, your question was a little misleading because you were talking about "making" and "building" (i.e., compiling) a stack, but you want to create one instead. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you are developing under ROS Groovy or newer, the idea of a "stack" has been replaced by the idea of a "metapackage". See [Metapackages and the Elimination of Stacks](http://ros.org/wiki/catkin/conceptual_overview#Metapackages_and_the_Elimination_of_Stacks)

Metapackages are essentially "empty" packages that group related packages together through runtime dependencies (`<run_depends>`)

You will want to learn more about catkin (the preferred build system in groovy and newer): http://ros.org/wiki/catkin

In particular, here is some info about metapackages: http://ros.org/wiki/catkin/package.xml#Metapackages

And here is an example of a metapackage: https://github.com/roadnarrows-robotics/hekateros/tree/master/hekateros

---

Originally posted by [dPackard](https://answers.ros.org/users/4911/dpackard/) with karma: 115 on 2013-08-12

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2